# Make apt install ignore missing packages

Tags: apt, stderr

I often find myself doing this: `:~$ sudo apt install php7.4 mysql-server git composer curl apache2 --yes`

To which I sometimes get this response:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package mysql-server is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'mysql-server' has no installation candidate
```

How can I avoid this? I tried redirecting stderr but got no luck. I googled to no avail but no one seems to be running into this scenario.

Basically, I want to throw apt install a bunch of packages I want to install, and if I get one wrong, I would like the program to continue with the rest.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`apt-get` (and `apt`) have a `-m` option to ignore missing packages.  From `man apt-get`:

> `-m`, `--ignore-missing`, `--fix-missing`
>
> Ignore missing packages; if packages cannot be retrieved or fail the
> integrity check after retrieval (corrupted package files), hold back those
> packages and handle the result.
>
> Use of this option together with `-f` may produce an error in some
> situations.
>
> If a package is selected for installation (particularly if it is mentioned
> on the command line) and it could not be downloaded then it will be silently
> held back.
>
> Configuration Item: `APT::Get::Fix-Missing`.

Comment: Thank you! This helped me a lot. Also I need to up my man pages reading abilities. Thanks again!